# MiniProfiler Entity Framework Core how to exclude calls to Open/Close?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, miniprofiler

In ASP.Net Core 2 web site we are using the latest (4-alpha9) MiniProfiler to see the SQL being generated.

Beside generated SQL, I also see a lot of calls to `Connection Close()/Connection Open()`:

[image]

They are fast and logging them seems useless to me.
Can I filter them out?
Some of them can be filtered out using `options.ExcludedMethods.Add("ConnectionOpening");` but not all of them.
Also, these calls seem to ignore `options.TrivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds = 3;` setting, that I also tried.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These timings cannot be turned off in the version you're using. We added the timings because they help show getting a connection from the pool, delays there, etc. But, I totally see how they can be noisy for a ton of use cases and agree this would be annoying.

I've just [added an option to control this in MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/commit/b39cbc63eb4eb84b5d665e22fd0658d41ebffb7e). If you grab latest from MyGet (the build should finish shortly) or NuGet later this week, you'll be able to use:

```
options.TrackConnectionOpenClose = false;
```